# Using a USB HDD being connected to trigger a scheduled task

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-task-scheduler

In the Windows Vista & 7 task scheduler you can chose an event to trigger a task to run.

I have been looking through various logs (mainly system & hardware events) and cannot seem to find any events that are triggered when my USB HDD is connected.

Yet I am sure that a event must be raised, so does anyone know what event it is (log/source/event id)?

Comment: Can't you use AutoRun on the HDD to trigger a task when you plug the HDD in the computer?

Comment: autorun is disabled on USB drives for security reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the setupapi.log

More info at http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/USB_History_Viewing

Comment: Link is dead - [downforeveryone](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/forensicswiki.org)